# Google Maps crashes after a while after a few clicks

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am having a problem where the google maps will start to slow down and crash after playing around with the draw area function (bottom of page). Wanted to know if I have missed something or I have something in there which is causing it to crash?

```html
var map;
var weatherDisplayIsOn = false;
var markers = [];
var cArea;

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.488651, -0.063232);
    var newYork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.719967, -74.009893);
    var paris = new google.maps.LatLng(48.857278, 2.352210);
    var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.519670, -0.125631);
    var towerBridge = new google.maps.LatLng(51.506231, -0.075356);
    
  
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 8,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            mapOptions);



    var Home = '<div id="content" align="center">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Home</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p><b>Home</b>, the buidling I had spent the last 13 years living ' +
            'in with the locality of Primary Schools, Secondary and Localised ' +
            'public transport ' +
            '</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

    var infoHome = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: Home
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'Homeland'

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoHome.open(map, marker);
    });


    var NewYork = '<div id="content" align="center">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">New York</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p><b>New York</b>, often called New York City or the City of New York to distinguish ' +
            'it from the State of New York, of which it is a part of the most populous city ' +
            'in the United States and the center of the New York metropolitan area, the premier gateway for' +
            'legal immigration to the United States and one of the most populous urban agglomerations in the world.' +
            '</p>' +
            '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MtCMtC50gwY?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
            '</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

    var nyInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: NewYork
    });
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newYork,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'New York'


    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
      nyInfo.open(map, marker1);
   
    });


    var Paris = '<div id="content" align="center">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Paris, France</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p><b>Paris</b>, is the capital and most populous city of France. ' +
            'Situated on the Seine River, in the north of the country, it is in the centre of the ' +
            'Ile-de-France region, also known as the region parisienne.' +
            '</p>' +
            '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hWo-43ObCP8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

    var parisInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: Paris

    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: paris,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'Paris'

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
        parisInfo.open(map, marker2);

    });

    var London = '<div id="content" align="center">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">London, United Kingdom</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p><b>London</b>, is the capital city of England and the United Kingdom.' +
            'It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over ' +
            '13 million inhabitants. ' +
            '</p>' +
            '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/45ETZ1xvHS0?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

    var londonInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: London

    });
    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: london,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'London'

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
        londonInfo.open(map, marker3);
    });

    var TowerBridge = '<div id="content" align="center">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Tower Bridge,London</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p><b>Tower Bridge</b>, is the capital city of England and the United Kingdom.' +
            'It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over ' +
            '13 million inhabitants. ' +
            '</p>' +
            '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/45ETZ1xvHS0?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

    var towerBridgeInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: TowerBridge
        
        

    });
    var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: towerBridge,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'Tower Bridge'
        
       
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function() {
        towerBridgeInfo.open(map, marker4)
         
    });


    weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
        temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.CELCIUS
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('weather'), 'click', toggleWeather);

    
  };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



function setRoad() {
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
}

function setHYB() {
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
}

function zoomTo() {
    var lat = prompt("Enter your latitude");
    var lng = prompt("Enter your longtitude");
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
}

function zoomIn() {

    var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (currentZoomLevel != 21) {
        map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel + 1);
    }
}

function zoomOut() {

    var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (currentZoomLevel != 21) {
        map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel - 1);
    }
}

function toggleWeather() {
    if (weatherDisplayIsOn) {
        weatherLayer.setMap(null);
        weatherDisplayIsOn = false;
    }
    else {
        weatherLayer.setMap(map);
        weatherDisplayIsOn = true;
    }
}

function addMarker(myLatlng) {

    var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });

    markers.push(customMarker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    });

}


function setAllMap(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

function clearMarkers() {
    setAllMap(null);
}

function showMarkers() {
    setAllMap(map);
}

function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
}

function toggleBounce() {

    if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}

function drawArea()
{
 
 var points = new google.maps.MVCArray();
       

 var endPoint = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


 cArea = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: points,
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
                  fillColor: "#FF0000"
   });

   cArea.setMap(map);

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e)
 {
  var path = cArea.getPath();
  path.push(e.latLng);
  endPoint.extend(e.latLng);
                addMarker(e.latLng);
  
 });
}

function deleteArea(){
    
    cArea.setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ showing your problem? would be easier to try and debug..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/368b5e1t/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/368b5e1t/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this function:

```
function addMarker(myLatlng) {
    var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });

    markers.push(customMarker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}
```

In which you define an event listener for map clicks, which calls... the addMarker function... which defines an event listener for map clicks, which calls... the addMarker function... which defines an event listener for map clicks,... etc etc ad infinitum.

In other words, the error is probably too much recursion.

And to cap it all, you also define the same event listener elsewhere too:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e)
{
    var path = cArea.getPath();
    path.push(e.latLng);
    endPoint.extend(e.latLng);
    addMarker(e.latLng);
});
```

Although this seems to be in a function ('drawArea') that isn't called from anywhere.

Just move this outside of the addMarker function, to wherever you create the map:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
     addMarker(event.latLng);
 });
```

Comment: I don't think "recursion" is the right word, since `addMarker` in the event handler isn't run when the handler is added. It's more likely to be that the first handler adds another handler, so the next click runs two handlers and then adds a third, etc.

Comment: @duncan Thanks worked perfectly ! The lag has stopped and has stopped crashing. I will keep stress testing it. Hopefully that is the last I see of it